# Program won't search subfolders

Tags: python

I have this Python program where I'm splitting images into three subfolders. I want to make a new folder with parts from the original three. I setup my OS to do that for me but it won't search the subfolder and I don't know why or how to fix it.
Code:

```
# Path to the directory where the original DS was uncompressed
original_dir = 'datasets/catsvdogs'

# Directory to store my smaller dataset
base_dir = 'datasets/catsvdogs/catsvdogs_small'
os.mkdir(base_dir)

# Directories for the training, validation, and test splits
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
os.mkdir(train_dir)
validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'valid')
os.mkdir(validation_dir)
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')
os.mkdir(test_dir)
```

Error:

> `No such file or directory: 'datasets/catsvdogs\\cat.0.jpg`

I don't know why it wont search in datasets/catsvdogs/train etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `\` is the separator `os.path.join` is using, I suspect you're on Windows.

Provided you're executing this code from the directory that also contains `datasets`, try replacing your first two lines of code with this.

```
original_dir = os.path.join('datasets', 'catsvdogs')
base_dir = os.path.join(original_dir, 'catsvdogs_small')
```

If that `\` *isn't* being added by `os.path.join` (since we can't see it from the code you've provided), then it looks like your code at that point may erroneously be using the wrong slash.

Comment: Thank you It didin't fix the problem directly but i managed to fix it.